# Redux: build a reducer for a subelement of a main reducer

Tags: redux

Possibly a silly question. I have a Redux reducer built from an Immutable.js record:

```
export const Editors = new Record({
    'editors': new List(), // this is a list of Editor items below
})

export const Editor = new Record({    
    'id': null,
    'state': EditorState.createEmpty(),
    'annotations': new List(),
});
```

I've structured things this way, because I expect the application that I am building to have many editors.

However, I want to write an `updateState` action that updates the state of an individual editor. I imagine that it would be much easier to write this if I was able to write reducer code that acts on a specific `Editor` rather than on the list of `Editor`s in my `Editors` reducer. Is there a way to write reducer code so that I can just update state on a field in an individual editor, rather than finding the editor in the list, removing it, updating it, re-inserting it, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Editors = new Record({
    'editors': new Map(), // this is a list of Editor items below
})

export const Editor = new Record({    
    'id': null,
    'state': EditorState.createEmpty(),
    'annotations': new List(),
});
```

Then updating an editor becomes:

```
const updateEditorState = (Editors, id, editorState) =>
   Editors.setIn(['editors', id, 'state']¸editorState)
```

Your naming is a bit weird, by the way. I would lower case `Editors` and `Editor`.